Can't get GridContainer's child size
It worked once, but in a wrong place. I changed some container size flags, and now it's been 3 hours since all went wrong(
The problem:
I have NinePatchRect (1) inside another NinePatchRect (2) inside GridContainer. I need to pass outer (2) rect's size to the inner (1) one. Both NinePatchRects have textures set at runtime. As I'm working within a container the only way to get starting size would be to set an anchor for (2), otherwise the size would equal to (0, 0). And I can actually see the size.x value change in the editor after assigning the anchors. BUT, once the code is executed, by the time I get to the size.x value, it becomes 0. Even though the texture is placed and shown correctly.
NPR (2) has following size flags:
Horizontal Fill Expand
Vertical Fill
NPR (1) is set to layout_mode POSITION at the position of NPR (2). If I use any anchors, I won't be able to change the size of the rect (which I need to do dynamically).
I actually have a RichTextLabel (of the same size I could use) nearby within the same GridContainer, and I can't get its size value as well, as it turns to (0, 0).
Question:
How do I get the size of GridContainer's child?
Edit:
I did find this post on godot forums which seems to be what I need, but the trick with idle frame doesn't work, as I still get size (0, 0)


NPR (1) is set to layout_mode POSITION at the position of NPR (2). If I use any anchors, I won't be able to change the size of the rect (which I need to do dynamically).

You should be able to. Setting the anchor will make the Control resize automatically, but it won't be setting its size every frame, but only when the container resizes. And, yes, the position properties are hidden in the inspector but you should be able to still write them from code.
Anyway, if you rather the Container didn't set the size at all, you can use a Control (a plain old Control) inside the Container. So the Container sets the size of that Control and inside of that Control you can add whatever you want with anchors or setting the size form code.
And finally, you can connect the resize signal of that Control so the children can react when the container changed it.


How do I get the size of GridContainer's child?

A Control inside of a Container will know its own size, the same as if it wasn't in a Container. Now, I understand that you might not know that size before the Container sets it. For that you might want to listen (or await) to the resized signal.

I did find this post on godot forums which seems to be what I need, but the trick with idle frame doesn't work, as I still get size (0, 0)

In the linked page they have this line:
yield(get_tree(),"idle_frame") # yield until the next idle frame

That is Godot 3 code. In Godot 4 you would something like this:
await get_tree().process_frame

In this case we are awaiting the process_frame signal of the scene tree.

Using a separate Empty control to get the size kinda works, but the second suggestion (awaitng process frame) works more cleanly, "kinda". I was debugging it with some print statements, and I noticed my prints appeared before the editor's debugging tool got to the break point I placed after the await. So, my follow-up question is: does awaiting the process frame signal separates the function execution into a separate thread, sort of? Cause now it does what I need exactly, it just does it later.

@DotFX As far as I know, after the await the execution will be resumed in the main thread. So if you were using a secondary thread, that might be a thread change.

I explained it poorly, my bad( but the important thing is AWAITING PROCESS FRAME works! If it doesn't, put it in another place (just for myself in the future). Now, to what I explained poorly: I have 2 functions, 1 setup (was with await), 2 update (with prints). One right after the other. With me awaiting the process frame in setup, the prints from the 2nd func appeared before the setup was finished. Thus, rewriting my updates. So I moved the await later down the line, and it works perfectly now) Thank you, again:D
